# How to run exported AnyLogic model from Docker container?

Tags: docker, anylogic

I have an exported model which runs without errors locally. I want to containerize this model to distribute and run elsewhere on a computer that does not have Java installed. For testing purposes I am currently using a simple call center model.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /app/CallCenterExported

ENV PATH="$PATH:/app/CallCenterExported"

CMD ["CallCenter_linux.sh"]
```

The error when I run the container:

```
chmod: cannot access 'chromium/chromium-linux64/chrome': No such file or directory
Couldn't find browser: chromium/chromium-linux64/chrome. Attempting to open system-default browser for url: http://localhost:29602
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error attempting to launch web browser:
Cannot run program "which": error=2, No such file or directory
        at com.anylogic.engine.internal.l.k(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.launch(Unknown Source)
        at com.anylogic.engine.gui.IExperimentHost.launch(Unknown Source)
        at call_center.Simulation.main(Simulation.java:313)
```

The error makes sense to me since the image only has openjdk, and I didn't tell it to install Chrome anywhere. However, after googling and testing several ways to install chrome in the container's image from the docker file, I have not found a way that works. Does anyone have a working method to run an anylogic model from a docker container?

Thank you!!

Comment: You may try to use a full Ubuntu image that already has it and install OpenJDK manually. Or other distro that you like.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a Docker container, you can simply ship Java with your compiled model:

1. Copy the desired JRE or JDK into the compiled model folder
2. adjust the model batch file: add a new variable `set PATH_XJAL="jdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe"`. It should look like this:
   [image]
3. Also, you need to now use the `PATH_XJAL` variable to tell the model to use this Java version. Simply replace `java` after `echo on` with `%PATH_XJAL%`:
   [image]

NOTE: Since AnyLogic v8.8, it compiles in Java 11. So any Java version shipping with your compiled model must support v11 or up. Java v14 seems to be a good version to be applied.